# Utilizing hardware AI accelerators with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tpu

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, but also to using PyTorch. I'm an AI and CS major, and I'm working on a project involving processing video with ML models. I'm not going to get into the details because I want any answers to this question to be generally accessible to others using pytorch, but the issue is I'm using pytorch with vapoursynth at the moment, accelerating both with CUDA, but I'm looking into purchasing as AI accelerator like this:

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08TZRX2WP)

Documentation on using these with Tensorflow is pretty easy to find, but I'm having trouble trying to answer for myself how I can use one of these with PyTorch. Does anybody have experience with this? I'd simply like to be able to use this card to accelerate training a Neural Net.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that you would need to convert your code to run on XLA, but that includes only changing few lines in your code. Please refer to https://github.com/pytorch/xla README doc for references and guides. With few modifications you can get significant training speedup.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the info. I appreciate the link to relevant resources

Answer (score 0):

I think the experience of using Pytorch on TPU would be less smooth than it on nvidia GPU. As far as I know, you have to use XLA to convert pytorch models to make them able to run on TPU.

Comment: I would appreciate a more concrete answer, with a link to relevant resources, but yes my gut instinct was the same. Thanks.